# grep to search data in first column

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

I have a text file with two columns.

```
Product   Cost
Abc....def  10
Abc.def     20
ajsk,,lll   04
```

I want to search for product starts from "Abc" and ends with "def" then for those entries I want to add Cost.
I have used :

```
grep "^Abc|def$" myfile
```

but it is not working

Comment: Do you need the code like this? `grep "^Abc.*efg$" `

Comment: the data i am searching is in first column, however there are two columns in a row

Comment: Hum, could you edit your question and add a example of your file?

Comment: If you found one of the answers suitable, could you please mark it as an accepted answer to give closure to your question? Thank you, @Aquarius24

Comment: See this answer for grep'ing on a column: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/287018/84897   `awk '$1 ~ /^Abc.*def/{print $2}'` This will also cut the second column.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use awk. `cat myfile | awk '{print $1}' | grep query`

Comment: This exhibits _two_ common antipatterns from the [useless `cat` award](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) page.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use `awk`, try this:

```
text.txt
--------
Product   Cost
Abc....def  10
Abc.def     20
ajsk,,lll   04
```

With only awk:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^Abc.*def$/ { SUM += $2 } END { print SUM } ' test.txt
```

Result: `30`

With grep and awk:

```
grep "^Abc.*def.*\d*$" test.txt | awk '{SUM += $2} END {print SUM}'
```

Result: `30`

Explanation:

- `awk` reads each line and matches the first column with a regular expression (regex)
- The first column has to start with Abc, followed by anything (zero or more times), and ends with def
- If such match is found, add 2nd column to SUM variable
- After reading all lines print the variable

Grep extracts each line that starts with Abc, followed by anything, followed by def, followed by anything, followed by a number (zero or more times) to end. Those lines are fed/piped to awk. Awk just increments SUM for each line it receives. After reading all lines received, it prints the SUM variable.

Comment: You generally want to avoid the [useless use of  `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) in the second variant. It can be convenient for quick experiments, but you usually want to avoid it in production code.

Comment: The `.*` wildcard in the `grep` variant also allows the match to straddle column boundaries, so it's not really correct. It can be fixed with a better regex, but the Awk-only solution is already correct, and obviously simpler and clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks edited. Do you want the command like this?

```
grep "^Abc.*def *.*$"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use cat, and also show the line numbers:

```
awk '{print $1}' filename | grep -n keyword
```

Comment: Presumably the OP wants to _print_ the whole line, but restrict the search to the first field.

Answer (score -1):

If applicable, you may consider caret ^: `grep -E '^foo|^bar'` it will match text at the beginning of the string. Column one is always located at the beginning of the string.

[Regular expression > POSIX basic and extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended)

```
^ Matches the starting position within the string. In line-based tools, it matches the starting position of any line.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).